# Using variable date in column header

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I  am trying to create a dashboard showing forecasted materials.
The forecast is updated every week and i would like the header of the weeks/months to be variable.

I start my SQL with declaring the periods.

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME);
DECLARE @CurrentWeekNumber INT = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE());
DECLARE @Week01 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @Today), 0);
DECLARE @Week02 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week01);
DECLARE @Week03 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week02);
```

I use them to select the sum of the forecasted material in that peiode.

But i would like to have `AS 'Week 01',` as a variable showing the actual date or week number.

Eg. `@Week01` returns 2024-01-29 00:00:00.000

If i try to use `AS @Week01,` i get incorrect syntax error.

```
SELECT
  t0.ItemCode,
  t1.OnHand,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week01 AND t0.Date < @Week02 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 01', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week02 AND t0.Date < @Week03 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 02',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week03 AND t0.Date < @Week04 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 03',
```

COMPLETE CODE:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME);
DECLARE @CurrentWeekNumber INT = DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE());
DECLARE @Week01 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @Today), 0);
DECLARE @Week02 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week01);
DECLARE @Week03 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week02);
DECLARE @Week04 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week03);
DECLARE @Week05 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week04);
DECLARE @Week06 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week05);
DECLARE @Week07 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week06);
DECLARE @Week08 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week07);
DECLARE @Week09 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week08);
DECLARE @Week10 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week09);
DECLARE @Week11 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week10);
DECLARE @Week12 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week11);
DECLARE @Week13 DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Week12);
DECLARE @Month01 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @Week12) + 1, 0);
DECLARE @Month02 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month01);
DECLARE @Month03 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month02);
DECLARE @Month04 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month03);
DECLARE @Month05 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month04);
DECLARE @Month06 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month05);
DECLARE @Month07 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month06);
DECLARE @Month08 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month07);
DECLARE @Month09 DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @Month08);

SELECT
  t0.ItemCode,
  t2.U_din AS "FP. Artikel Nr.",
  t2.ItemName AS "Beskrivelse",
  t1.OnHand AS "Lagerbeholdning",
  t1.IsCommited AS "Indv. Ordre",
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week01 AND t0.Date < @Week02 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 01', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week02 AND t0.Date < @Week03 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 02',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week03 AND t0.Date < @Week04 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 03',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week04 AND t0.Date < @Week05 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 04',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week05 AND t0.Date < @Week06 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 05',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week06 AND t0.Date < @Week07 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 06',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week07 AND t0.Date < @Week08 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 07',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week08 AND t0.Date < @Week09 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 08',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week09 AND t0.Date < @Week10 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 09',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week10 AND t0.Date < @Week11 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 10',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week11 AND t0.Date < @Week12 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 11',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week12 AND t0.Date < @Week13 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 12',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Week13 AND t0.Date < @Month01 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Week 13',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month01 AND t0.Date < @Month02 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 01',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month02 AND t0.Date < @Month03 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 02',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month03 AND t0.Date < @Month04 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 03',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month04 AND t0.Date < @Month05 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 04',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month05 AND t0.Date < @Month06 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 05',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month06 AND t0.Date < @Month07 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 06',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month07 AND t0.Date < @Month08 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 07',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month08 AND t0.Date < @Month09 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 08',
  SUM(CASE WHEN t0.Date >= @Month09 THEN t0.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month 09'
FROM FCT1 t0
LEFT JOIN OITW t1 ON t1.ItemCode = t0.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN OITM t2 ON t2.ItemCode = t1.ItemCode
WHERE t0.AbsID = 7 AND t1.WhsCode = '01'
GROUP BY t0.ItemCode, t1.OnHand, t1.IsCommited, t2.ItemName, t2.U_din
ORDER BY t0.ItemCode ASC;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2019

Comment: This is a job for the presentation layer, not the SQL layer. The SQL should return 1 row per week, and then the presentation layer can pivot that

Comment: If you really wanna do it, you can use dynamic sql. it might also save you on the copypaste thingy. Also, please, avoid "quoted" aliases like "FP. Artikel Nr.", use [aliases]